# How to edit a file in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have a CPP file. I am using VB in VS2005. I have opened that file using the `FileSystemObject`. I am reading each and every line in that CPP file. I have to comment all the lines until I encounter a return statement. I am using the `scripting.textstream` to read a line from the CPP file. But I have no idea as to how we can add a `//` comment to the beginning of every line that I read or even a multiline comment from the beginning till a return statement. Please help.

Comment: Are you using VB6? If not, why are using FileSystemObject & related classes?

Comment: I'm assuming this has been tagged correctly, and the use of the FSO amounts to the limited familiarity of the OP with the framework classes. On the other hand, it may also turn out to be a legacy application requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the `FileSystemObject` of the Windows script runtime instead of the System.IO.File class's methods. Strange!

The static `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` will read a file (and close it) and return a string array containing all the lines. You could then iterate through the array and add a comment to each line (except if the line starts with `return`).

Finally, save the changed text to the file using any of the `WriteAllLines()` method, thus overwriting any contained text.

Adding a multiline comment at the start would be even easier, you would not need to read the lines into an array.

Comment: If there are any multiline comments in the file though these will break it. You're better off prepending // to every line that comes through